# GeoServer Image Mosaic time dimension is disabled

Tags: raster, geoserver, ndvi, image-mosaic

I am trying to create NDVI map for 100 tiles. For each tile I have more than 10 TIFF files belonging to different dates. To do that, It appears that the Image Mosaic module can be useful with the time series.

Before I start, I tried to repeat the example in the GeoServer documentation:

https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html

Followed each step but without database. I created timeregex.properties file, a store and point that folder which includes snow TIFFs, afterwards I created a layer and go to the dimensions tab to enable time dimension.

It looks like it is disabled with a warning: `Cannot enable, no attribute of type Date found`

Does anyone know how I can proceed?

GeoServer version: 2.19.2

My timeregex.properties file:

`regex=[0-9]{8}`

My Folder:

```
sample_image.dat
snowExample.dbf
snowExample.fix
snowExample.prj
snowExample.properties
snowExample.qix
snowExample.shp
snowExample.shx
snow_20091001.tif
snow_20091101.tif
snow_20091201.tif
snow_style.sld
timeregex.properties
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing the `indexer.properties` file.  It should contain something like:

```
TimeAttribute=ingestion
Schema=*the_geom:Polygon,location:String,ingestion:java.util.Date
PropertyCollectors=TimestampFileNameExtractorSPI[timeregex](ingestion)
```

The tutorial (https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html) isn't clear in this, but the file is needed even if you aren't storing the data in a database.

Comment: Exactly! At first, I thought that indexer files are only being used for remote database usage. Once I created as you suggest, I am able to enable the time dimension. Appreciated!